# Notice: Undefined variable:( PDO )

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been trying for over 5 hours to understand why my query doesn't return my database values, I've tested with a different query to return my _iD which equls my User ID and I am able to connect but I'm having a tough time with this.. I keep getting..
I wouldn't ask if I wasn't seriously stuck.

> Notice: Undefined variable: _iPassword on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: _iUsername on line 8

```
public function User_Login($_iUsername,$_iPassword) {

    $md5_password = md5($_iPassword);

    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT _iD FROM users WHERE _iUsername = :username AND _iPassword = :password AND _iStatus = 1");
    $sth->bindValue(":username", $_iUsername, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(":password", $md5_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->execute();

    if ($sth->rowCount() == 1) {
        $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $row['_iD'];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

this is the query in MySQL which I'm converting but I have no idea what could be wrong..

```
public function User_Login($username,$password) {
    $username=mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password=mysql_real_escape_string($password);
    $md5_password=md5($password);
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT uid FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$md5_password' AND status='1'");

    if( mysql_num_rows( $query ) == 1 ) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array( $query );
        return $row['uid'];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the db field called `_iPassword` (as per query#1) or `password` (query#2)?

Comment: yes, the dabata field is _iPassword, I updated every field in the database from $.. to _i...!

Comment: what are lines 5 and 8?

Comment: $sth->bindValue(":username", $_iUsername, PDO::PARAM_STR);
AND
$sth->bindValue(":password", $md5_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: This should not be possible, the variables are clearly defined. `$db` **isn't** though.

Comment: I know, I've been cracking my head for over five hours over this. $db is defined in db.php which I call this in a class, I just changed it to make it easier here, as I have made a query to return my iD and it works, so I don't know what the issue is..

Comment: @AttisBarros, it's a variable scoping issue. take a look at my answer

Comment: Please read the friendly manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: How are you CALLING the User_Login() - function?

Comment: With the first example I gave above with the PDO query.

Comment: @AttisBarros - ? I don't see it. It's just the notices, not the actual call. The call is like: $this->User_Login({value}, {value});

Comment: Don't rely on rowCount()-function in PDO. Do the fetch() and check if the fetched query is empty or not instead.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason you omitted a filename from the error message, while it is going to be the critical part.

```
$sth->bindValue(":username", $_iUsername, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(":password", $md5_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

lines cannot be lines 5 and 8 as they are obviously consecutive AND there are more than 5 lines from the beginning of the script.

So, either this error occurred in whatever else file or you are editing one file but running another.

Please double-check all these simple typo-like mistakes and surely you will find the problem